# Array length is 0 while it has items

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, firebase

I am filling an array with test data in this example so I know the firebase data isn't to blame.

```
this.lastMessages = new Array();

ref.limitToLast(1).on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
   this.zone.run(() => {
       this.lastMessages.push("test");
   });
});

console.log(this.lastMessages);
console.log(this.lastMessages[1]);
console.log(this.lastMessages.length);
```

In this example I just push the value "test" into the lastMessages array to make it easier. Now I have 3 logs on the bottom which gives weird results.

The first one logs as expected:

```
[]
0: "test"
1: "test"
2: "test"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The second log returns undefined and the last log gives me 0 back as length. I made sure by pushing values it does not become associative. Now it couldn't be because it is running in zone since the first console log gives me the right representation. What is going on?

Comment: what is `ref.limitToLast(1)`?

Comment: This is a call to firebase to give me the last entry of a firebase database model. I am not doing anything with firebase data in this example but still showing the function since it does push values within it

Comment: A Side Note: Please be aware of the Nested Arrow function with `this`. Arrow function binds the `this` reference to the lexical scope, which can be an issue with Nested Arrow functions.

Comment: Is there a chance that your on("child_added"... zone.run(...) is running after your console.log()?  It looks like this is an event driven system, that depends on the events running before the code after it.

Comment: Yet another synchronous check over an array which is expected to get populated asynchronously.  Duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of expecting `aync` to be `sync` and the chrome developer tools showing the reference array.

the `ref.limitToLast(1).on` makes the whole 'adding' process async, which means that when you log the array there are no elements in it yet, because the async part has not fired yet. Check it by placing a `console.log` above the `this.lastMessages.push`. You will see that the logging of 'add' is done after the logging of the array

The reason it does show 3 items is because of a browser optimization. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320181/console-log-showing-only-the-updated-version-of-the-object-printed) for more details

Comment: Great answer, indeed it works in the function itself. Have you got any idea how I can bind it to this.lastMessages inside the function so it does display in my template?

Comment: can you post your entire `@Component`?

Comment: Any way we can chat? My component is big.

Comment: I've started a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151283/room-for-pierreduc-and-davida)