# Cannot iterate over a local array of objects in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to Angular 6 and I'm trying to iterate over an array of objects but it's producing nothing. People online are talking about subscribing to the observable and I can't figure out how to do that if it's the problem.

This is my component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Topic } from '../topic';
import { TopicFetcherService } from '../topic-fetcher.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topics',
  templateUrl: './topics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topics.component.css']
})
export class TopicsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private topicFetcher: TopicFetcherService) { }

  topics: Topic[];

  ngOnInit() { 

    // this grabs my topics from my http service
    this.processTopics(this.topicFetcher.getData()); 

  }

  processTopics(rawTopics: Topic[]) {

    console.log(rawTopics); // this works 

    rawTopics.forEach(topic => {
      console.log(topic.id); // this does not work ? 
    });

  }

}
```

I don't understand why console.log(rawTopics) works but if you try to iterate over it, you have to get involved with observables. That seems a little heavy handed.

EDIT:

This is my topic-fetcher service. It currently just .get's a .json file in assets:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Topic } from './topic';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TopicFetcherService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  topics: Topic[];

  getData(): Topic[] {

    this.topics = [];
    let index = 1;

    this.http.get('assets/topics.json')
    .subscribe(data => {     
      for (const key in data) {
        let topic = new Topic();
        topic.id = index;
        topic.title = data[key].topic;
        topic.description = data[key].narrative;
        topic.type = data[key].type;
        topic.dataset = data[key].dataset;
        this.topics.push(topic);
        index++;
      }
     });

     return this.topics;

  }

}
```

Comment: What does the working console log output?

Comment: It outputs an array in the console, which you can click on and then you see all the individual Topic objects and their properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: But I'm able to return the response no problem? I can even log the array of objects to the console and see everything perfectly. I just can't iterate over it?

Comment: @AzzyDude That's because the code is asynchronous. The items are not being added to the array until after you try to iterate

Comment: I think I understand, but why can I log the entire array to the console if the items haven't been added to it yet?

Comment: Try logging the length of the array, you should see it's zero. When you log the object to the array, the console actually holds a reference to the object, so will update when you expand, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320181/console-log-showing-only-the-updated-version-of-the-object-printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getData()` returns an observable of type `Observable<Topic[]>`, you need to subscribe (and unsubscribe) to it. At first import Observable

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

and in your component class

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.processTopics(this.topicFetcher.getData()); 
}

processTopics(rawTopics$: Ovservable<Topic[]>) {
  rawTopics$.subscribe((rawTopics) => {
    console.log(rawTopics); // this works 

    rawTopics.forEach(topic => {
      console.log(topic.id); // this does not work ? 
    });
  });
}
```

It is a good practice to mark observables by `$` at the end, but that is primarly opinion based.

**Unsubscribe**

To unsubscribe it makes sense to introduce the `OnDestroy` component livecycle hook and unsubscribe in there.

```js
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

Add a member to your component class, e.g. named `subscription: Subscription`. Then assign the subscription in `processTopics` to that variable.

```js
this.subscription = rawTopics$.subscribe(...)
```

Tell the component class to implement the ondestroy livecycle hook.

```js
export class TopicsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {}
```

And finally create the hook function

```js
ngOnDestory() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Change your service to the following snippet (of course with all your object properties and not ...). Do not subscribe in the service itself, but return the `http.get` as an observable and subscribe in your components.

```js
getData(): Observable<Topic[]> {
  return this.http.get<Topic[]>('assets/topics.json').pipe(
    map(data => {
      data.map((entry, index) => {
        const topic = {
          id: index,
          title: entry.topic
          ...
        }
        return topic;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Also `http.get` requests have the advantage that they also complete when the observable receives a value, means, you don't have to unsubscribe to them. But it really can curse your application with performance issues when you have got too many unwanted subscriptions.

Comment: If I switch Topic[] to Observable<Topic[]> I get a really weird error... "Argument of type 'Topic[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Topic[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Topic[]'"

Comment: I highly recommend to rework your `getData` method as it is in my edit. You should return the http.get directly and don't subscribe in the service itself.