# JSON.parse() returns different values for local and global variable

Tags: json, angular, typescript, parsing, subscription

I am working on an Angular application, that listens to the MQTT broker. I am trying to parse the response with JSON.parse() function. It looks simple, but I can't get the correct data to my global variable.

I am publishing this data (id of light and rgb value of that light) :

```
[{"light":2,"color":{"r":150,"g":24,"b":24}},{"light":3,"color":{"r":150,"g":24,"b":24}},{"light":4,"color":{"r":150,"g":24,"b":24}},{"light":6,"color":{"r":150,"g":24,"b":24}},{"light":7,"color":{"r":150,"g":24,"b":24}}]
```

The code looks like this.

```
export class LightsComponent implements OnDestroy {

  lightsValues;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private mqttService: MqttService) {
    this.subscription = this.mqttService.observe(TOPIC).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      this.lightsValues = JSON.parse(message.payload.toString());
      console.log(JSON.parse(message.payload.toString()));
      console.log(this.lightsValues);
    });
}
```

The result of console.log is the weird part, as I am only assigning the same **JSON.parse()** to the variable as into the console.log - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj8BY.jpg

As you can see, the **light** parameter is set to 0 for all objects, **rgb** is set correctly.

However, when I change the **lightsValues** variable to local like this, I get the correct data.

```
export class LightsComponent implements OnDestroy {

  lightsValues;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private mqttService: MqttService) {
    this.subscription = this.mqttService.observe(TOPIC).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      let lightsValues = JSON.parse(message.payload.toString());
      console.log(JSON.parse(message.payload.toString()));
      console.log(lightsValues);
    });
}
```

With this code, the data is correct in both console.logs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbl2E.jpg

I need to get this correct data to my global variable, as it serves as an @Input for my other component.

```
<app-lights-preview [lightsValues]="lightsValues"></app-lights-preview>
```

The child component :

```
export class LightsPreviewComponent {

  @Input() lightsValues;
.
.
.
```

Comment: This is the lazy behaviour of the console: it retrieves the properties of logged objects at a later time, so if the object is mutated later, you see that effect in the console. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320181/console-log-showing-only-the-updated-version-of-the-object-printed)

Comment: You were right, console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lightsValues))) solves the issue, but I still don't understand why does it work with the local variable and not with the global one.

Comment: The local variable never changes again. The next time this function is called it is another variable that is created. So the reference that the console has is still to the other version of that local variable: it no longer changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console.log showing only the updated version of the object printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320181/console-log-showing-only-the-updated-version-of-the-object-printed)