# Object has contents, as long as I don't want to specifically adress them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, javascript-objects

I have this React project, in which I fetch data from a firebase database and construct a object called "statehelp" from the results. Now for some reason, if I console log the whole statehelp Object I get all its contents, however if I want to access statehelp.contents or statehelp.products they are undefined.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  var statehelp = {
    content: {},
    products: {}
  }

  getFarm(this.id).then(result => statehelp.content = result)
  getProduct(this.id).then(result => statehelp.products = result)
  console.log(statehelp)
  console.log(statehelp.content)
}
```

Comment: It is likely that you are trying to access the data before it has been stored.

Comment: how would I remedy that then ?

Comment: You could set a condition to see if the data has been received before you access it.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because console.log() is synchronous operation. It won't wait for your api call to happen. So don't use console.log() as a metric for identifying whether your object got populated or not.

Comment: I see, but the thing is that the first console.log has the whole object with its updated contents, but the second doesn't.

Comment: When you log statehelp, is the structure what you expected it to be?. Like the keys content and products are present with required values?

Comment: exactly, that's why I'm confused

Comment: @Irrelefant because browser's logs are *lazy*. The first log logs the `statehelp` object to the console. It's properties are loaded freshly everytime you expand it. By the time you expand the object, `.then(result => statehelp.content = result)` would've populated the object. If you log `JSON.stringify(statehelp)` , you'll notice it is empty when it was logged `https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320220/3082296

Comment: Okay, first off thanks for your answer. 
What would I now need to do if I wanted the contents of "statehelp" in the state of my component?