# currentUser in getAuth() has value, but getAuth().currentUser is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing with React and Firebase.
I was working on creating a feature where the user's name and photo are displayed in the `<NavBar />` component upon logging in.
I learned that I can use `onAuthStateChanged()` for this, but I was curious, so I have a question.

```js
const auth = getAuth();
console.log(auth); 
console.log(auth.currentUser);
```

First, I logged in with Google using `signInWithPopup()`.
I assigned the value returned by `getAuth()` to a constant called `auth`.
`console.log(auth)` prints an object containing information about the currently logged-in user, including `currentUser`.

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
console.log(obj.a); // 1
```

I thought `console.log(auth.currentUser)` would work similarly to the above code, but it prints `null`.
I expected it to show the information of the currently logged-in user since `console.log(auth)` shows a non-null `currentUser`. I'm confused why `auth.currentUser` is `null` when `console.log(auth)` shows a value for currentUser.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
I couldn't find any other answers besides using `onAuthStateChanged()`, so I'm asking again.

Other values like `auth.config` are showing up fine.

Comment: Why do you say that `console.log(auth)` shows a non-null currentUser?  What are you observing?  Please edit the question to be clear what is not working the wah you expect.

Comment: I will also note that, generally, you are not supposed to inspect the internal private details of an object and make assumptions about them.  Just because you see something in a dump of the private details of an object does not mean you can make assumptions about what's going on inside that object. Use only the documented APIs, and use them only as the documentation says to use them.  Anything else is not guaranteed to work the way you expect.

Comment: How you are using the auth in your Navbar componet ? can you please explain that if there may be setup problem ??

Comment: Because of the side-effect of the Google developer console, the `currentUser` was non-null when I did `console.log(auth)`. It was my first time using stackoverflow, so I was kind of bad at asking questions. Sorry. I'll be careful from now on.
Thank you all for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're seeing an (often useful, but at times like this annoying) side-effect of the Chrome developer console: it patches objects after you've logged them. For an explanation of this, see [Console.log showing only the updated version of the object printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320181/console-log-showing-only-the-updated-version-of-the-object-printed)

So the flow is probably something like:

0. No user is signed in yet. Upon reloading the page that is the initial state, as restoring the persisted user requires a call to the server and is an asynchronous operation.
1. You log the `auth` object, which at that point does *not* contain a current user - but you can't see this value yet.
2. You log the `auth.currentUser` object, which is `null`. You can see this value right away.
3. The user is restored by Firebase, and assigned to `auth.currentUser`.
4. You open the `auth` object in the developer console, and... see the current user.

If you want to test this, you can log `JSON.stringify(auth)` - as that'll capture the current value at the moment of logging.

Comment: Thank you so much! As you mentioned, it was a side-effect of the Chrome developer console issue. When I checked with `JSON.stringify()`, it worked as expected.